# Is there a way to couple two HTML select dropdown lists using only PHP and HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, dropdown

I want to be able to select a product from two select dropdown lists, e.g. productcode and product name. If I select the productcode I want the corresponding product name to show up in the other select dropdown list and vice versa. So I want to couple every productcode and product name that are on the same row in my MySQL database. I prefer to do this with only HTML and PHP but any other solutions are welcome to.

code snippet of what i am working with:

```
          <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="productChoice">
                        <?php
                            if ($resultCheck > 0){
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    $ordercode = $row['productcode'];
                                    echo "<option> $productcode </option>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="productChoice">
                    <?php
                            mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
                            if ($resultCheck > 0){
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    $productName = $row['name'];
                                    echo "<option> $productName </option>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

Comment: In PHP you'll want to post the choice of the first select via a form, then your PHP script will create a page with both selects. You'll still need an onChange event in the HTML. Does this lead you in the right direction?